# Find average of an array of ints

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

**Given a task**

Return the "centered" average of an array of ints, which we'll say is the mean average of the values, except ignoring the largest and smallest values in the array. If there are multiple copies of the smallest value, ignore just one copy, and likewise for the largest value. Use int division to produce the final average. You may assume that the array is length 3 or more.

```
centeredAverage([1, 2, 3, 4, 100]) → 3
centeredAverage([1, 1, 5, 5, 10, 8, 7]) → 5
centeredAverage([-10, -4, -2, -4, -2, 0]) → -3
```

**I tried to solve it like that, but I little confuzed**(catch ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] num = {1, 2, 3, 4, 100};
        int[] num1 = {1, 1, 5, 5, 10, 8, 7};
        int[] num2 = {-10, -4, -2, -4, -2, 0};
        System.out.println(centeredAverage(num));
        System.out.println(centeredAverage(num1));
        System.out.println(centeredAverage(num2));
    }

public static int centeredAverage(int[] nums) {
    int count = 0;
    int average = 0;
    //to search for max and min
    Arrays.sort(nums);
    //the last int of an array
    int end = nums[nums.length - 1];

    if (nums.length > 3) {
        //exclude minimum and maximum values
        for (int i = 1; i < end; i++) {
            if (!(nums[i] == nums[i + 1])) {
                count++;
                average = (nums[i] + nums[i + 1]) / count;
            }
        }
    }

    return average;
}
```

}

Comment: Shouldn't that be easy to do? Sum all the elements and keep track of the smallest and largest value. Subtract them from the sum and divide by array length - 2. With sorting it would be summing up elements from index `1` to index `length - 2` and then dividing by `length - 2`.

Comment: in `(int i = 1; i < end; i++)` it should be `i < end - 1`

Comment: @Amongalen that's wrong. `i < end` is comparing an _index_ and a _value_ (`end` is the last value in the array). It should be `i < nums.length - 2`. (-1 to stay in the index range and -2 to get the second to last element).

Comment: @Thomas true, for some reason I've thought `end == nums.length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll expand a little on my comment to your question:

Your solution would be to first sort the array and then skip the first and last elements. That's sound thinking but the implementation is wrong:

- `int end = nums[nums.length - 1];` should be `int end = nums.length - 1` since it seems you mean `end` to be the index of the last element
- `average = (nums[i] + nums[i + 1]) / count;` is wrong inside the loop since you're dividing way too often. Also that line would mean you add just 2 elements and divide that by `count`. That's not the average of all array elements except the smallest and largest.
- `if(nums.length > 3)` is unnecessary since "You may assume that the array is length 3 or more." (and if you want to use that condition it should be if `if(nums.length >= 3)`)
- `if (!(nums[i] == nums[i + 1]))` seems wrong, why would you skip consecutive elements with the same value? You're already skipping the first and last elements.

Your code should thus look like this:

```
int sum= 0;
//to search for max and min
Arrays.sort(nums);
//the last int of an array
int end = nums.length - 1;


//exclude minimum and maximum values which are at index 0 and "end"
for (int i = 1; i < end; i++) {               
   sum += nums[i];
}

int average = sum / nums.length - 2;
```

One drawback of your approach would be that you're altering the array that's getting passed since sorting is an in-place operation. You'd thus have to at least make a copy of the array if that shouldn't happen.

You also don't need to sort at all, just keep track of the smallest and highest elements:

```
int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int highest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int sum = 0;

for( int value : nums ) {
  sum += value;
  smallest = Math.min(smallest, value); //or use if(smallest > value) smallest = value;
  highest = Math.max(highest , value);  //or use if(highest < value) highest = value;
}

//smallest and highest are part of the sum so subtract them again
//since we ignore 2 elements we divide by length - 2
int average = (sum - smallest - highest) / (nums.length - 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that instead of storing the length-2 in end, you are storing the value at length-1 in end.
Declare end as :

```
int end = nums.length - 2;
```

And one other thing I noted:

if (nums.length >**=** 3)

Comment: Note that `int end = nums.length - 2;` and `i < end` would skip the second to last element as well. It should be `int end = nums.length - 1;` or `i <= end` :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
public static int centeredAverage(int[] nums) {
//array to ArrayList
ArrayList<Integer> list = (ArrayList<Integer>)Arrays.stream(nums)     
                                .boxed()        
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
//Sorting the ArrayList
Collections.sort(list);
//Removing first and last number
list.remove(0);
list.remove(list.size()-1);
//Returning the average
return (int) list.stream().mapToDouble(val -> val).average().orElse(0.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now my solution for same question in codingbat.com (https://codingbat.com/prob/p136585) is correct for all possible combinations. Detailed Answer is as follows:

```
public int centeredAverage(int[] nums) {
  //first find Min and Max
  int min=nums[0], max = nums[0];
  for(int i=1;i<nums.length;i++){
    min=Math.min(min,nums[i]);
    max=Math.max(max,nums[i]);
  }
      
  int total=0,count=0,mincount=0,maxcount=0;
  for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
    //exclude min and max only once to total count
    if(nums[i]==min&&mincount==0) {
      mincount++;
        continue;
    }
    else if(nums[i]==max&&maxcount==0) {
      maxcount++;
        continue;
    }
    //find total excluding min and max number only once
    total+=nums[i];
    //also count the numbers included in total
    count++;
  }
    //return average
    return total/count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Set up the **max** and **min** value we can possibly get.
2.Let **int total** counts the sum of all values in the array.
3.Set up **two conditions** which are when nums[i] is greater than max, and when nums[i] is less than min. If the condition is met, assign the nums[i] value to max/min.
4.Finally, minus the max and min value from total and **calculate the average value.**

```
public int centerAverage(int[] nums)
int max= Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int min= Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int total=0;
for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
 total+=nums[i];
 if(nums[i]>max){
  max=nums[i];
 }
 if(nums[i]<min){
  min=nums[i];
 }
}
return (total-max-min)/(nums.length-2);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this too.

```
public static int centeredAverage(int[] nums) {
        
       Arrays.sort(nums);
        
       double Average = Arrays.stream(nums, 1, nums.length - 1)
                                    
                            .average()
                                    
                            .getAsDouble();
         
        return (int)Average;
    }
```